# Is CSS/javascript import required separately when you embed external url in iframe?

Tags: javascript, css, url, iframe, embed

I have imported an external url within iFrame in my web-app. Wanted to know whether I need to separately import the CSS and Javascript files associated with that external url or will they anyways come when i have embedded it ?

```
<iframe id="btw_footer" style="width:100%;overflow:hidden;height:42px;frameborder=0px;" src="www.google.com"></iframe>
```

Comment: Iframe is a sperate document, when you load a URL it loads the page as expected with all its resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not to do anything else, iframe src will carry everything with it.